# component to vga cable not giving video

Tags: conversion, cable

I bought [these composite to vga cables](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10235&cs_id=1023503&p_id=2409&seq=1&format=2) to go from the YPbPr ports on [these dvd players](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007F9XHBI) to a "standard" lcd monitor's vga port.

Unfortunately, they don't work. The best results I can get are green and blue colors to come through on any given monitor.  Other monitors don't show any output at all.

This sort of thing should work, right?   Any help/advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this part? "This cable DOES NOT CONVERT VGA signals to component video or vice versa - it functions only with devices that use the VGA connector for component video. "

Comment: nope, missed that part.  crap.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. Absolutely legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

VGA is RGBHV (horizontal and vertical sync) not YPbPr so without active adapting hardware, it isn't going to work.  The formats are not compatible as the addressing information is missing.    You might be able to find a dual mode monitor that has support for both formats on the connector (some video mixers do for example), but it would be luck of the draw and pretty rare.